# Saber si ya ha iniciado sesión

Tags: php, android

Buenas, estoy desarrollando una aplicación en Basic 4 Android y le he colocado un "splash screen" al iniciar, lo que quiero hacer es que al iniciar la aplicación saber si ya tiene una sesión iniciada, es decir si no ha dado clic en "Cerrar sesión", ya que cuando cierro la aplicación, elimina los datos y se cierra la sesión. Estoy usando una base de datos en MySQL y la conexión la realizo mediante un documento php en el host, en la aplicación con los campos de texto se obtienen los datos y se envía la query al documento PHP, les muestro un poco del código.

```
Sub btn_acceder_Click
ExecuteRemoteQuery("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE jUsuario = '" & txt_usuario.Text & "';", "accediendo")  Sub ExecuteRemoteQuery(Query As String, JobName As String)
End Sub

Dim job As HttpJob
job.Initialize(JobName, Me)
job.PostString("http://*****/condb.php", Query)
End Sub

Sub JobDone(Job As HttpJob)
ProgressDialogHide
If Job.Success Then
    Dim respuesta As String 
    respuesta = Job.GetString
    Dim parser As JSONParser
    parser.Initialize(respuesta)
    Log("Respuesta del servidor: " & respuesta)
    Select Job.JobName
        Case "accediendo"
            funciones.limpiar(respuesta)
                If (funciones.jUsuario = txt_usuario.Text) And (funciones.jClave = txt_contrasenia.text) Then
                    ToastMessageShow("Datos encontrados, accediendo" & Job.ErrorMessage, True)
                    StartActivity("home")
                Else
                    Msgbox("La contraseña ingresada es incorrecta", "")
                End If
    End Select
Else 
    Log(Job.ErrorMessage)
    ToastMessageShow("Error: " & Job.ErrorMessage, True)
End If
Job.Release
End Sub
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿La sesión la quieres controlar en el lado de la aplicación o en el del servidor con php?

Comment: Supongo que lo mejor sería por el lado de la aplicación. Gracias por responder.